# Query row and join many rows as JSON array

Tags: postgresql

I am looking to join three tables via ids, the outcome being three json columns with the content from each.

The issue I am facing is that for each `cat_request` there are many `cat_request_fields`, I am currently getting `cat_request_fields` as one object and not an array of objects.

This query gets me a result set with `cat_requests` and `cat_request_fields`.

```
SELECT
    row_to_json("cat_requests") AS cat_request,
    array_agg(row_to_json("cat_request_fields")) AS cat_request_fields
FROM
    "cat_requests"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "cat_request_fields" ON "cat_requests"."id" = "cat_request_fields"."cat_request_id"
GROUP BY
    "cat_requests"."id"
LIMIT 10;
```

This query gets me a result set with `cats` and `cat_requests`.

```
SELECT
    row_to_json("cat_requests") as cat_request,
    row_to_json("cats") as cat
FROM
    "cat_requests",
    "cats"
WHERE
    "cat_requests"."cat_id" = "cats"."id"
LIMIT 1;
```

I'm looking for a query that will give me a combination of the two...

How can I modify this query to map the `cat_request_fields` to be an array of rows and not just one.

Comment: It would really help to see some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: @S-Man updated with more info

Comment: It is hard for me to see what is the problem with joining three tables. For me a minimize sample data and the expected result would help much more.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    row_to_json("cat_requests") AS cat_request,
    (select row_to_json("cats".*) as cats from "cats" where "cats"."id" = "cat_requests"."cat_id"),
    array_agg(row_to_json("cat_request_fields")) AS cat_request_fields
FROM
    "cat_requests"
    INNER JOIN "cat_request_fields" ON "cat_requests"."id" = "cat_request_fields"."cat_request_id"
GROUP BY
    "cat_requests"."id"
LIMIT 6;
```